# Joining data from 3 mysql tables (syntax)

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to get data from 3 tables, joining on 2 different values. I am used to Oracle, and am doing something wrong with regard to aliasing. Can someone help me with this?

```
SELECT r.idreservation, r.first, r.last, r.StartDay, r.NumberOfDays, g.First, g.Last, l.location
  FROM reservation r, guides g, Locations l 
  WHERE r.guide = g.idguides 
    AND r.location = l.idlocations 
    AND r.StartDay >= dateString
```

Do I need single quotes around the dateString? r.StartDay is of type DATE.

Comment: At first sight, nothing *really* shocking. How does *this* failed? Is there some error message (i.e.: "syntax error"), or the query didn't produce what you expected?

Comment: Oracle or MySQL? And what is not working?

Comment: Can you format the query properly ? It's hard to tell whether it's formatting issue or real problem, but I can see there is no space between "l.location" and "FROM reservation r".

Comment: @a1ex07 Good catch. Same missing space between "Locations l" and "WHERE ..."

Comment: It is notably (?) difficult to properly format SQL request. At the very last you should try to group the various clause on their own lines as I did while editing your question. To answer, you should only put quotes around [literal strings](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html). Single or double quotes are acceptable. You will probably choose one or the other in order to *not* conflict qith the quoting style you use in your host language.

Comment: yeah, you need single quotes around `datestring`  (your initial post, before all the edits is actually more informative than the current version)  and make sure you put a space at the end of each line/section of concatenated string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got it: you probably only have some "quotes" issue:

```
"SELECT r.idreservation, "r.first, "
                         ^
```

and

```
+ "r.StartDay >= "+dateString"
                 ^
```

As a hint to catch those errors, you should only have even number of quotes on the same "line". Probably you will have to use *simple quote* to delimiter strings inside your *double-quotes* strings.

As a final advice, if your host program language allow that, maybe multi-line strings will be more readable that concatenation as you did. In addition that would avoid "missing space" error as you in your example (see the comments).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT r.idreservation, r.first, 
 r.last, 
 r.StartDay, 
 r.NumberOfDays, 
 g.First, 
 g.Last, 
 l.location
 FROM reservation r, 
 guides g, 
 Locations l
 WHERE r.guide = g.idguides AND 
 r.location = l.idlocations AND 
 r.StartDay >= dateString
```

OR

```
SELECT r.idreservation, r.first, 
 r.last, 
 r.StartDay, 
 r.NumberOfDays, 
 g.First, 
 g.Last, 
 l.location
 FROM reservation r 
 INNER JOIN  guides g
 ON r.guide = g.idguides
 INNER JOIN  Locations l
 ON r.location = l.idlocations
 WHERE r.StartDay >= dateString;
```

Comment: Could you highlight the difference with the original query?

Comment: r.first,r.last etc considered as variables in program